# javascript, subtracting a number from a string

Tags: javascript, subtraction

can anyone help please, there seems to be many terms for what im looking for but still unable to fatham the answer?

Im using javascript to to get the window height then subtract 40 px to give me the value of the rest of the available space, but it gives me 'invalid argument' and im not sure why

```
var WH=$(window).height();
var TopSpace=40;
var AvailSpace=WH-TopSpace;
document.getElementById("BottomSpace").style.height=AvailSpace;
```

When the page loads fresh, it shows an Invalid Argument, if i press F5 it does the job??

Many thanks

Comment: Add console lines, what is the value of WH? Are you calling it before the element BottomSpace is loaded?

Comment: worked fine for me .!!  http://jsfiddle.net/Y9JnR/

Comment: Maybe you will need to put this inside document ready section. Did you try it?

Comment: jvilhena is right; with your formula you get a number, but dimensions must have px or % unit measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using jquery to get the window height, why not use it go change the style of the "BottomSpace"? I tested your code, and the problem (at least in Safari) is that you don't set the units in the height, so either use jQuery for it, or set the unit (px). Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fvjsd/2/).

```
var WH=$(window).height();
var TopSpace=40;
var AvailSpace=WH-TopSpace;
//$("#BottomSpace").height(AvailSpace);
document.getElementById("BottomSpace").style.height=AvailSpace + "px";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, i used jquery to get the height as i dont know how to do it in javascript ( im not very good, just a newbie and copy other people code to learn somthing that works ), i also tried to look at the link but it crashes and says somthing about compatability.

Comment: ah okay, i have copied the copied the code and going to have a play with it, thanks again

Comment: DUUUUUUUUUUUUUUDE!!!!!!!
you are a hero!!!!
 i have been trying for weeeks to get that sussed, i removed my bottom and yoused the one in the comment ans it worked.
however when i tried it my lappy well messed up ans slowed down, just hoping it nots related lol

Comment: UPDATE, many thanks i have played with the code and now understand more about jquery, thanks again